# Wordpress template page.php

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I have problem creating a page.php for wordpress template. All functions work, but problem is that loop doesn't give me page content. Instead, it gives me last post. I have standard loop:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    the_title();
the_content();
endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: Your syntax is correct, check this out http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop_in_Action I don't think the problem lies in that particular snippet, we will need you to give more information to give a good answer.

Comment: @RichardMiles i found problem but i don't know how can i solve it.
Above this loop i have this code
http://pastebin.com/7M93DbBY
how can i reset query data?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. I've deleted get_post and now using WP_Query